# Using an Iterator in a parallelized foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, iterator

I've just learned what an iterator is in R, and what's in the Iterators package. I see an application of it for my code, mostly to save memory in parallelized calculations.

My analogy of what I am doing is to find a neighborhood around a particular address from a list of 100,000 addresses. In my current code, I have a dataframe of all 100K addresses, and my foreach loops over each address to do a calculation. In my dopar loop, I pass the entire list of 100K addresses for each calculation. What I want to do is pass only the 10 nearest addresses for each address that is the current target of the computation, thereby saving memory. Each process only needs its 10 nearest neighbors, not the whole 100K list of addresses.

Here is my question: is it sufficient to create an iterator over each target address (which is easy), and then use that as an argument in a function call to return a neighborhood to pass to the dopar loop, or does my function that identifies each 10-home neighborhood need to be the iterator?

Comment: Can you provide an example to understand more what you want?